# No matter what, Motion tracking WILL NOT align with scene

Tags: tracking

I'm absolutely ripping my hair out at this. Followed 9 different tutorials, and used more than a dozen different clips I've gone out and recorded, to no avail. I've always managed to get a solve error less than 1 on a 4k clip, but no matter what I do or what settings I set the tracking scene moves completely differently than the clip. I even recorded a clip where I am walking forward, with as little rotational movement as possible, literally the easiest shot to motion track and still the tracking scene moves completely differently than the video clip. the markers that show up in the tracking scene don't line up with the background video. I'm about 8 years deep into blender at this point and i've done motion tracking before, but back when blender was still in 2.79. Have they changed things?

before you all ask, yes I set the scene frames, made the framerates match, input my camera info, tried using all the refine features, manually edited the distortion settings, all that. And I can get great tracks, some as low as 0.35 in some cases, but the scene that is created seems to just not follow the video at all. It moves in such a way it's like I had a solve error of more than 100 pixels, it's so strange. Setting the scene scale doesn't work, and picking tracking markers to use as the floor and stuff doesn't make a single difference. I've even downloaded clips from other peoples motion tracking tutorials and followed the EXACT same steps, but the same thing happens. WTF am I doing differently? Is my blender messed up?

Comment: It would help to show exactly the problem you are having, using screenshots of GIFs would help understand what's going on. Ideally, it would greatly help if you could make a sample scene showing the issue, uploading it on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your question to add the download link so that we can check ourselves how you did things and what's happening.

Comment: Thank you, I don't quite have the time to make a sample scene cause all the videos I used I ended up deleting it all, so I decided to skip using blender completely and I'm just handling all the tracking in after effects and porting it to blender. It's  still not perfect for some reason so it must be the video, even though I know the exact specs of my camera and moved it in an easy to track way. I'll keep experimenting and If it persists I will edit or start a new question with a link to a demo file but thank you! It's the only thing in my opinion that needs work in blender